# How to ignore an item when generating the json string if the value is None?

Tags: json, scala, option-type, argonaut

I'm trying to use [Argonaut](http://argonaut.io) to generate JSON string from a Scala instance.

```
import argonaut._, Argonaut._

case class Person(name: Option[String], age: Int, things: List[String])

implicit def PersonCodecJson =
  casecodec3(Person.apply, Person.unapply)("name", "age", "things")

val person = Person(Some("Freewind"), 2, List("club"))

val json: Json = person.asJson

val prettyprinted: String = json.spaces2
```

It will generate:

```
{
  "name" : "Freewind",
  "age" : 2,
  "things" : [
    "club"
  ]
}
```

And when the name is `None`:

```
val person = Person(None, 2, List("club"))
```

It will generate:

```
{
  "name" : null,
  "age" : 2,
  "things" : [
    "club"
  ]
}
```

But actually I want it to be:

```
{
  "age" : 2,
  "things" : [
    "club"
  ]
}
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Resolved, the key is to define custom EncodeJson rule and use `->?:` and `field.map`:

```
implicit def PersonCodecJson: EncodeJson[Person] = EncodeJson((p: Person) =>
  p.name.map("name" := _) ->?: ("age" := p.age) ->: ("things" := p.things) ->: jEmptyObject)
```